# PID (a proportional–integral–derivative controller) loop with a different command and feed back units/ types

Tags: c#

I have a laser and I am adjusting it's position using a motor, and I am reading the laser light intensity at the top and bottom using a sensor.

then I divide the top from the bottom and the goal is to get around 0.97%. This is called delta, if delta is too high, you move the motor lower and if delta is too lower we move it up.

now I coded a PID ( A proportional–integral–derivative controller), the program I have my command is in motor steps(position) but my feed back is in light intensity percent.

so how do I set up my PID ? can I even use a PID this way ?

here is my code:

```
 GetValue()
 {

  PID_controller PID = new PID_controller(2, 1, 0);
  ****

 stepsize = (int)PID.UpdatePID(Convert.ToDouble(stepsize), delta);
             stepsize = changeStepSize( stepsize);


  ***

             }
 public PID_controller(int Proportional, int Integral, int differential)
    {
        this.Proportional = Proportional;
        this.Integral = Integral;
        this.differential = differential;
         Istate = 0D;
        error_counter = 0;
         lastposition = 0;
    }


    double getPTerm(double command , double position)
    {
        double error = command - position;

        Istate += error;
        error_counter++;
        return error;
    }

    double getITerm()
    {
        double Integralvalue = Istate / error_counter;
        return Integralvalue;
    }

    double getDTerm(double position)
    {
        lastposition = position;
        double differential = lastposition - position;
        return differential;
    }

   public double UpdatePID( double command, double position)
    {
        double error = getPTerm(command, position);
        double perror = getITerm();
        double derror = getDTerm(position);
        command = (Proportional * error) + (Integral * perror) + (differential * derror);
        return command;
    }
```

Comment: Please reconsider a new title for your post, as "[PID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_identifier)" is a well-established acronym with a different meaning (you never said what it means for you, either).

Answer (score 0):

> the program I have my command is in motor steps(position)

This is your control variable: the value you can control.

> my feed back is in light intensity percent.

This is your process variable: the value you observe.

> I have a laser and I am adjusting it's position using a motor, and I am reading the laser light intensity at the top and bottom using a sensor. then I divide the top from the bottom and the goal is to get around 0.97%. This is called delta, if delta is too high, you move the motor lower and if delta is too lower we move it up.

If you divide the top by the bottom, you will never get negative error. Even if you implement the difference between positive/negative error manually, your control response will be skewed. Ignoring divide by zero issues, if you have positive error (laser too high), your error value will be anywhere between 0 and positive infinity. But if you have negative error (laser too low), your error will be between 0 and 1. You'll be feeding your controller much larger error values when the beam is too high than when it's too low.

Unless this is your desired behavior, you should use the *difference* between the top and bottom sensor output as your process variable error, in which case your set point would be ~0.03.

If you're looking for a C# PID controller to use, check out [CSPID](https://github.com/w-bonelli/CSPID) (disclaimer: I'm the developer).